# Silverlight website sometimes showing a blank window while navigating

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight application with multiple pages which are being navigated to within a frame control. However there is this one page, while navigating to, suddenly makes the window go blank, which gives me no choice, but to refresh the application. This only occurs rarely, but I would like to know the reason for it and if it could be stopped.

Answer (score 0):

(sorry for my bad english)

Probably there is some exception happening. On your `App.xaml.cs`, put a breakpoint on the `Application_UnhandledException` method and see if it is being called when you navigate to the page. If it is, `e.ExceptionObject` contains the exception that is causing this problem.

Comment: I tried throwing the exception message in the Application_UnhandledException method. But it is not being called. So i guess that it is not an exception that is occurring. Are there any other causes for this?